# UIView AnimateWithDuration handles to fast

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:20.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         cloudA.frame = CGRectMake(cloudIMG.frame.size.width/2, 0, cloudIMG.frame.size.width, cloudIMG.frame.size.height);
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
```

I have this code, it works fine on the iPad (iOS 7.0), but on my iPhone (iOS 7.1) it handles the same animation within a second.

Comment: The only thing that would make sense is `cloudIMG` being different, since you're changing between iPad and iPhone. Can you check the printout from `cloudIMG.frame`?

Comment: @GuyKogus No that wouldn't explain it. Duration is duration.

Comment: On iPhone are you getting the repetition and reversal that you asked for? If not, you are probably setting the frame (or position, or size) in other code and thus canceling the animation entirely.

Comment: @matt the code itself is obviously fine, there's something around it that isn't. Can we see some more code, please?

Comment: @Matt I'll post some more code soon. I think that the problem is that the iPhone isn't animatie at all. It's just repeating the first and last frame extremely fast.

Comment: Things to try (maybe you did, but please add to question if you did): 1) simplify options (to nil), 2) animate other props of cloudA, 3) animate frame of some other view.  Also, please clarify: it takes "a second" to animate when not working?  The animation happens at different duration  is a weird failure mode.  Not animating at all is much more common.

Comment: "First and last frame extremely fast" is a good clue: $20 bucks says that view's frame has auto layout constraints in one idiom, but not in the other.

Comment: @danh I'll check it, but I'm quite sure that it hasn't. Why would it otherwise work on the iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange because this problem only appears on iOS 7.1, could this be a bug or something?
Anyway, I found out that pausing the animation and start it again solved the problem.
Because of that I added a delay to the animation function which was directly called from ViewDidLoad, and everything seems to work fine now.