# Segue delays UIButton highlight

Tags: ios, uibutton

Please check EDIT 3

I have a UIButton that upon pressing I need to see it grayed out immediately. Im using this code as the declaration:

```
UIButton *myButton;
myButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];    //[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(132, 375, 40, 40);
buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chat.png"];
[myButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonInvoked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[cell.contentView addSubview:myButton];
```

And here's the method that the button triggers

```
- (void) myButtonInvoked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *catchButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     catchButton.alpha = 0.4;
                     catchButton.enabled = NO;
                 }
                 completion:NULL];   
    
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"hereToThere" sender:self];
}
```

Im using the **UIAnimation** code to make the button grayed out upon pressing, notice that it has a delay of 0, yet the **UIButton** is graying out with a delay. How can I get rid of this delay? I need *myButton* to immediately gray out.

**Edit**

I have now tried adding `commentsButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;` and also tried setting the image for the button in UIControlStateNormal and highlighted to an image which is the same, but gray.. that delays as well.

However, if I place an `NSLog` at the beginning of the method, I can see that it print immediately upon the touch of button, so why cant it immediately update the image? I have completely tried everything with the following to try and get this to work:

> A) highlighting
>
> B) changing of the image
>
> C) changing of the alpha of the UIButton

I have also put this in the method to see if it would work.

```
catchButton.highlighted = YES;
[catchButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chatHighlighted.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

**EDIT 2**

I just set up a simple UIButton exactly the same way with a @selector(methodHere:) and the alpha changes immediately. There must be some other cause that makes this delay? Super confused now.

**EDIT 3**
by commenting out the very last line in the `myButtonInvoked:` method above(see below):

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"hereToThere" sender:self];
```

.. setting the `myButton.alpha = 0.4` triggers immediately(visually) and the problem is gone. Why is this happening, and how can I get around this problem?

Comment: that is duration bro not the delay, duration is how much time it play the animation , see the link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23832780/uiview-animatewithduration-handles-to-fast

Comment: Good catch and suggestion.. tried the code in the link, as pertinent to my situation... still experiencing the delay

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 //0.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut//UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat |
                 animations:^{
                     catchButton.alpha = 0.4;
                     catchButton.enabled = NO;
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

delay happen: because you are using

```
animateWithDuration = 5 second
```

Comment: can you provide code fragment so that i can observe the delay

Comment: delay happen because you are using animateWithDuration = 5 second

Comment: No, unfortunately I just tried your code and it still delays. Also, Im pretty sure duration has to be set to something other than 0 or it will never occur.

Comment: how long the delay is

Comment: but i can't see the delay

Comment: to check more set "alpha = 0.0"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93098/discussion-between-jamil65able-and-chisx).